# Will adding a MessageHeaderAttribute nullable property, like a string, break the endpoint for other consumers?

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf, c#-4.0

I want to add a MessageHeaderAttribute to a WCF end point that other endpoints are already consuming. Will adding a nullable property, like a string, break the endpoint for other consumers?

Specifically, do the other consumers need to have the updated service contract? If their endpoint definition is missing this property, will it break the service for them?

So, some consumers do not know that the ActionType property has been added to the contract. Will those consumers still be able to consume it?

```
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(), _
 System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0"), _
 System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName:="UploadFileMessage", WrapperNamespace:="http://...", IsWrapped:=True)> _
Partial Public Class UploadFileMessage

    <System.ServiceModel.MessageHeaderAttribute([Namespace]:="http://...")> _
    Public DocumentId As String

    <System.ServiceModel.MessageHeaderAttribute([Namespace]:="http://....")> _
    Public ActionType As String
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to test and verify that I can safely add nullable parameters. I wasn't able to test non-nullable parameters. Sorry I don't have more information.